# Programming language that allows for more eye-catching graphic interfaces?

Tags: java, user-interface, programming-languages, customization

I have programmed in Java and although offers many possibilities for the graphic customizable interface, it is always enclosed in 4 lines (which form the rectangle) ... I know (because I've used it) that you can modify the edges of the application, make round or polygonal, but you have to get deep in the code and that can be tedious.

There are some other language (Java or tool) that allows for the really striking graphical interfaces, without suffering much programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't bother switching languages, you could try C++ with openframeworks.
That library allows you to use openGL in a simple way.

Comment: Nice man. I dont mind to change the languaje, i mean, i'm a quick learner, I think i'll make some research for that (who knows, maybe i got some pretty interfaces with that too). Thx man

Answer (score 1):

It may be time to retool.  Java is still a great language for enterprise-type development.  However, what is hot now, and will be for the next several years is full-stack development with javascript.  Node on the backend, Angular or some other declarative framework on the front end (jQuery is popular now, but it is imperative and not really a framework, just a DOM manipulator).  Now you can have an integrated environment, one language, and you can concentrate on css, html5, and tons of javascript-based libraries to do practically anything you want to do.

Just my opinion (so of course this will be voted down)

Comment: We are here to share knowledge, no way i could vote you down. I use html+css+jquery+js (for my webs apps and some freelance projects) but i was researching for something more like Java "local" stuff just like @fransschreuder said. Thx man. ;)